# MYSQL How to search for accent characters too?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm working on a search page for my site.
It has a lot of words with accent characters, like `éáűúöóü`, and I can't search for them with `REGEXP`.
So I started to use `MATCH(title)` AGAINST `("+*$string*")` but it doesn't helped at all.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 $string = "Éric Cantona";
$strict = strtolower($string);

echo "After Lower: ".$strict;

$patterns[0] = '/[á|â|à|å|ä]/';
$patterns[1] = '/[ð|é|ê|è|ë]/';
$patterns[2] = '/[í|î|ì|ï]/';
$patterns[3] = '/[ó|ô|ò|ø|õ|ö]/';
$patterns[4] = '/[ú|û|ù|ü]/';
$patterns[5] = '/æ/';
$patterns[6] = '/ç/';
$patterns[7] = '/ß/';
$replacements[0] = 'a';
$replacements[1] = 'e';
$replacements[2] = 'i';
$replacements[3] = 'o';
$replacements[4] = 'u';
$replacements[5] = 'ae';
$replacements[6] = 'c';
$replacements[7] = 'ss';

$strict = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $strict);
echo "Final: ".$strict;
```